# DirectAccess status codes

Tags: direct-access

does anyone know if there exists information on the possible `Status` en `Substatus` connection states in Microsoft Direct Access? The information on [MSFT_DAConnectionStatus class (Windows) | msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh872329(v=vs.85).aspx) states that both properties are uint32's but that's not really helpful.

I know by experience that status code `2` means `ConnectedRemotely`...

Thanks, David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am late to the party, but I ran into the same issue today. I quickly determined that Get-DAConnectionInfo automatically generates some runtime types based on the output of the WMI class, they are:

"Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.DAConnectionStatus.Status" and "Microsoft.PowerShell.Cmdletization.GeneratedTypes.DAConnectionStatus.Substatus"

Meaning, you can query them directly in Powershell, I use the script provided [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fieldcoding/2017/05/18/powershell-tip-getting-enum-values-as-names-int-and-bit/). For sake of convenience I've included the list below:

Status Enum:

```
Name              Value
----              -----
ConfigChanged         0
ConnectedLocally      1
ConnectedRemotely     2
ActionableError       3
Error                 4
```

SubStatus Enum:

```
Name                                    Value
----                                    -----
Invalid                                     0
None                                        1
NAPUnhealthy                                2
StrongAuthorizationCredentialsNeeded        3
LocalDNSNamesPreferred                      4
NoDirectAccessPolicy                        5
InternetConnectivityDown                    6
CouldNotContactDirectAccessServer           7
NameResolutionFailure                       8
RemoteNetworkAuthenticationFailure          9
RemoteNetworkConnectivityDown              10
SomeRemoteNetworkResourcesNotResponding    11
MissingDAClientExperienceConfiguration     12
MissingProxyConfiguration                  13
ProxyCredentialsNeeded                     14
IPHTTPSCertificateNeeded                   15
IPv6Disabled                               16
FirewallDisabled                           17
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `Get-DAConnectionStatus` PowerShell commandlet? That gives you the current status in text form.

```
PS C:\Users\administrator> Get-DAConnectionStatus

Status    : ConnectedLocally
Substatus : None
```

Also, if you're trying to troubleshoot DA connection issues, have you seen the ["DirectAccess Client Troubleshooting Tool"](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=41938)?